# Limitar caracteres e exibir pontos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
if (i.link[E].href == "teste") {
 var u = i.link[E].type.substring(0,130) + "...";
}
```

Ele limita os caracteres em 130, e exibi os três pontos ao final do texto. No entanto, os pontos são exibidos mesmo que não haja mais de 130 caracteres, de forma que não faz sentido ter 50 caracteres e ter três pontos no final. Como faço para exibir os pontos apenas se o limite de 130 for atingido?

Comment: porque não adiciona `i.link[E].type.length > 130` no teu `if`? aí ele só aplica se o conteúdo tiver mais de 130...

Comment: Consegui. Eu acreditava que era simples mesmo, mas sou um iniciante em js. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque a validação do tamanho no `if`; assim, apenas entrará se o `href == teste` **e** o tamanho da *strin* for maior que *130*:

```
var u = i.link[E].type;

if (i.link[E].href == "teste" && u.length > 130) {
   u = u.substring(0,130) + "...";
}
```

Detalhe: caso tenha apenas 130 caracteres para exibir, lembre de *tirar os três pontos da conta*, ou seja, contaria o tamanho da *string* em 127.